Installing mod_wsgi requires C++ build tools 14 on Windows
I am trying to install Django following this tutorial: https://ahmadalsajid.medium.com/serve-django-applications-with-mode-wsgi-and-apache-on-windows-server-4d35ab2ac6b6
I am stuck at pip install mod_wsgi because of
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/

I followed the link and installed the C++ build tools, but it gave me version 17 instead of 14. I still get the same error message...
Is there a workaround? Is there a way to get the binaries (without a virus) instead of compiling?

I followed this answer to build it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262038/607033
I needed to click on "modify" and select "MSVC v14x ..." and the "Windows 10 SDK". It takes around 6GB space to compile a simple binary people could include to Apache or add to a repo.



vs_buildtools.exe --norestart --passive --downloadThenInstall --includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools

